# Row index not updated when using rows().every().remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I was trying to remove jquery datatables selected rows using

```
table.rows('.selected').every(function(){
    this.remove()
});
```

But I found that when one row is removed, the row index is not updated, so this will lead to chaos. So is there a convenient way to remove selected rows from a table, or should I update row index manually?

I'd like to apply some other operations on each row besides remove, so I don't want to use

```
table.rows('.selected').remove();
```

Comment: maybe I have lack of knowledge, is there a function called `every`, should not it be `each` ?

Comment: @erkaner [every](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()) was introduced maybe in v1.10.6.

Answer (score -1):

When I remove rows the index number is updated. Try the code blow.

Click a row. It will alert its index then delete itself. Try clicking the row after it which should now have the same index as the deleted row.

```js
$('table tr').click(function(){
  alert(this.rowIndex);
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Click to remove</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Click to remove</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Click to remove</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Click to remove</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Click to remove</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```